# Amazon ECS How to login to the EC2 service it is associated?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-ecs

After I initiated an Amazon ECS following [their tutorial](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/ECS_GetStarted.html) (But I don't recall there is one step that asks me for the key-pair information.)

After I set it up, I found that there is an extra EC2 in my EC2 instance list that starts to charge me money. I wonder what that EC2 is doing.

Is it the EC2 that is associated with ECS that I can start to build my own server on?

- If so, how can I log into it? (There is no key-pair information for me to log in. It says I need to log in via valid username-password pair, but I don't even know my username.)
- If not, how can I kill it? (Directly terminating it in EC2 service is not helping since it seems ECS will just start another one)

Answer (score 0):

1. The username will be `ec2-user`. ECS creates a launch configuration in which you can set key pair
2. ECS creates an autoscaling group you can find it under `ec2/autoscaling/home` you can edit this group and set min and desired to 0 this will shut down the instance automatically.